# Change button color inside the foreach codeigniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, button

I can not change the colors of buttons. Only shows green. See the image. I want each status has a color. buttons in different colors How do I change within the foreach ?

[image: My screen]

```
<?php
                $query = $this->sindico->get_listfinanceiro()->result();
                foreach ($query as $linha):
                    echo '<tr>';
                    printf('<td>%s / %s</td>', ($linha->numero_apart) ? :'/', ($linha->nome_usu));
                    printf('<td>%s</td>', $linha->data_pagamento);
                    printf('<td>%s</td>', "Bs:".$linha->valor_pagamento);

                    if (!isset($linha->valor_pagamento["PAGO"])):
                    printf('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">%s</button></td>', $linha->status_pagamento);

                    elseif (!isset($linha->valor_pagamento["PENDENTE"])):
                        printf('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">%s</button></td>', $linha->status_pagamento);

                    elseif (!isset($linha->valor_pagamento['NO PAGO'])):
                        printf('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">%s</button></td>', $linha->status_pagamento);
                    endif;
                    printf('<td class="text-center">%s</td>', '<div class="btn-group btn-xs"><button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-xs dropdown-toggle"  data-original-title="" title="">Action<span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right"><li><a href="editar/'.$linha->id_finan.'">Edit</a></li><li><a href="excluir/'.$linha->id_finan.'">Delete</a></li>' );
                    echo '</tr>';
                endforeach;
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some typo error... see in my `//here` comments
Hope I didn't miss anything.

```
<?php

        $query = $this->sindico->get_listfinanceiro()->result();
             foreach ($query as $linha) { //here
               echo '<tr>';
               printf('<td>%s / %s</td>', ($linha->numero_apart) ? :'/', ($linha->nome_usu));
               printf('<td>%s</td>', $linha->data_pagamento);
               printf('<td>%s</td>', "Bs:".$linha->valor_pagamento);

               if (!isset($linha->valor_pagamento["PAGO"])) { //here
                    printf('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">%s</button></td>', $linha->status_pagamento);
               } //here

                  elseif (!isset($linha->valor_pagamento["PENDENTE"])) { //here 
                      printf('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">%s</button></td>', $linha->status_pagamento);
                  } //here

                  elseif (!isset($linha->valor_pagamento['NO PAGO'])) { //here
                      printf('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">%s</button></td>', $linha->status_pagamento);
                  } //here endif removed.

    printf('<td class="text-center">%s</td>', '<div class="btn-group btn-xs"><button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-xs dropdown-toggle"  data-original-title="" title="">Action<span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right"><li><a href="editar/'.$linha->id_finan.'">Edit</a></li><li><a href="excluir/'.$linha->id_finan.'">Delete</a></li>' );
                                echo '</tr>';
    } //here, removed endforeach
                            ?>
```

Comment: Giroux 
it would be like then? you can say?

Comment: In PHP it suppose to be if (blabla) { instruction } see this  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php